# expo-barcode-scanner does not supports url like `mailto:${email}?subject=${encodeURIComponent(subject)}&body=${encodeURIComponent(content)}`

Tags: react-native, expo

I have the following the generate the content for the qr scanner

```js
generateQRContent: ({ email, subject, content }) => {
      let qrContent = `mailto:${email}`;

      if (subject) {
        qrContent += `?subject=${encodeURIComponent(subject)}`;
      }

      if (content) {
        qrContent += `&body=${encodeURIComponent(content)}`;
      }

      return qrContent;
    }
```

The following code is used to scan the qr:

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Camera, FlashMode } from "expo-camera";
import QRIndicator from "./QRIndicator";
import QRFooterButton from "./QRFooterButton";
import { calcHeight, calcWidth } from "../helper/res";
import * as BarCodeScanner from "expo-barcode-scanner";
import getLocalImage from "../helper/getLocalImage";
import getQrDataFromImage from "../helper/getQrDataFromImage";

import { useSafeAreaInsets } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

const CameraScanner = ({ handleBarCodeScanned, isLit, setIsLit }) => {
  const { bottom } = useSafeAreaInsets();
  async function getImage() {
    const image = await getLocalImage();
    const scannedResults = await getQrDataFromImage(image);
    if (scannedResults.length > 0) {
      handleBarCodeScanned(scannedResults[0]);
      return;
    }
    alert("No QR code found in image");
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.scannerContainer}>
      <Camera
        barCodeScannerSettings={{
          barCodeTypes: [BarCodeScanner.Constants.BarCodeType.qr],
        }}
        onBarCodeScanned={handleBarCodeScanned}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
        flashMode={isLit ? FlashMode.torch : FlashMode.off}
      />
      <QRIndicator />
      <View style={[styles.footer, { bottom: 30 + bottom }]}>
        <QRFooterButton
          onPress={() => setIsLit((isLit) => !isLit)}
          isActive={isLit}
          iconName="ios-flashlight"
        />
        <QRFooterButton
          onPress={getImage}
          iconName="ios-images"
          iconSize={48}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scannerContainer: {
    width: calcWidth(100),
    height: calcHeight(100),
    overflow: "hidden",
    zIndex: 1,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#000",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  footer: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    paddingHorizontal: "10%",
  },
});

export default CameraScanner;
```

When the QR code generated by the generateQRContent function is scanned using the barcode scanner, only the email address is passed to the handleBarCodeScanned function, and the rest of the string is omitted. For example, if the QR code contains the following data: test@gmail.com?subject=test&body=test, only test@gmail.com is extracted when scanning the QR code. How can I enable the scanner to capture the entire string? It's worth noting that when scanning the QR code with Google Lens, it correctly extracts all the data, which suggests that the issue is not with the generator.

Comment: similar issue is also metioned here: https://forums.expo.dev/t/expo-barcode-scanner-scan-result-is-changed/74990